# TypeError: string indices must be integers when read JSON via Python

Tags: python, json

I just face a problem when I try to read the variable name in JSON data.
Here is the sample Json dataset.

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "added_at" : "2015-01-15T12:39:22Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "id" : "jmpe",
      "type" : "user",
      "uri" : "youtube:user:jmperezperez"
    },
    "is_local" : false,
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "id" : "2pADiw4ko",
        "name" : "All The Best",
        "type" : "artist all the best"
      },
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 376000,
      "explicit" : false,
      "id" : "4jZ",
      "name" : "Api",
      "popularity" : 8,
      "track_number" : 10,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "youtube:track:4jZ"
    }
  },{
    "added_at" : "2013-05-30T15:49:25Z",
    "added_by" : {
      "id" : "jmpe",
      "type" : "user",
      "uri" : "youtube:user:jmperezperez"
    },
    "is_local" : false,
    "track" : {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "id" : "2pADiw4ko",
        "name" : "This Is Happening",
        "type" : "album this is happening"
      },
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 376000,
      "explicit" : false,
      "id" : "abc",
      "name" : "Api",
      "popularity" : 8,
      "track_number" : 10,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "youtube:track:abc"
    }
  } 
  ],
  "limit" : 100,
  "next" : null,
  "offset" : 0,
  "previous" : null,
  "total" : 5
}
```

I want to print all the type in the album under the track.

```py
for play_track in r['items'][0]['track']:
    type =play_track['album'][0]['type']
    print(type)
```

There is a error message.But I am not sure how to solve it.Thanks.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\code\track2.py", line 15, in <module>
    type =play_track['album'][0]['type']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `r['items'][0]['track']` is a **dictionary**. You are iterating over the dictionary's keys. It's not clear to me why you are using the loop in the first place. If you explain what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @FelixKling I just want to print the all 'type' name which are in 'album' under the 'track'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to print the all 'type' name which are in 'album' under the 'track'

Then you'd have to iterate over `items`:

```
for item in r['items']:
    print(item['track']['album']['type'])
```

Comment: Thanks.I can see the output.Does the have any way to bring the output like this? Type =['all the best','this is happening']

Comment: `[item['track']['album']['type'] for item in r['items']]`

Comment: when I try to use .split() to split type based on your above solution It failed. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. The ideal output I want to get type=['artist', 'all', 'the',' best','album',' this',' is',' happening']

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? You have a list of strings. If you want to do something with those strings, you have to iterate over the list. If you have a new problem then you should ask a new question. I think this one has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

`r['items'][0]['track']` is a dictionary.  Iterating over it with a `for` will list the keys, which are strings of course.

Comment: what does the [0] mean in ['items'][0]['track']

Comment: `r` is a dictionary; `r['items']` is an array in that dictionary; `r['items'][0]` is the "zeroth" (first) element in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code should be right:

```
import json
# test.json is your JSON data file.
with file(r'test.json') as f:
    jsonobj = json.load(f)
    for i in range(len(jsonobj["items"])):
        print jsonobj['items'][i]['track']['album']['type']
```